# Would it be good idea to share DNS zone files via NFS?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, nfs, dns-zone

Any expert advice on Bind DNS zone file transfer (master->slave) via NFS? Are there any drawbacks for not using Bind's zone transfer feature?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds a bit weird. Why wouldn't you use native zone transfers?

Answer (score 4):

DNS has proper built in replication, so why bother with something like that? You're introducing an unnecessary a single point of failure.

Especially when you'll still need to issue a reload of any updated zone files on both DNS servers, as simply updating the zone file does not make it active on either of the servers.